# Why can't you use values from the query string when constructing a for loop in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, query-string

This seems like a strange problem to me, but PHP seems incapable of using a variable passed from the query string when constructing a for loop.

As far as i'm aware there's no parsing required, and data coming from the query string should be...a string anyway.

Despite the fact I can print out the values once i've retrieved them from the query string, this does not work:

```
$from = $_GET['dealfrom'];
$to = $_GET['dealto'];

$fromDate = $from;
$toDate = $to;

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);

for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between
$currentDateStr = date("Y-m-d",$currentDateTS);
$dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
//print $currentDateStr.”<br />”;
}

echo  "<pre>";
print_r($dateMonthYearArr);
echo "</pre>";
```

If I set the values explicitly to strings ($fromdate and $todate) to exactly what i'm passing in the query string, then the code runs perfectly.

Is this a limitation of PHP in some way, or am I just missing something really obvious? Been banging my head on the wall over this one.

Comment: I have tried printing $from and $to and they are both set and print correctly. When it comes to using them to construct the for loop, it just refuses to work, no error messages at all (And i've set to show all errors)

Comment: There should be no trouble, I'd doublecheck both the `$_GET` variables to see if they actually contain you think they contain (be aware of whitespace, html tags, etc.), and the created `$from/toDateTS` after `strtotime`.

Comment: Print out the timestamps. It's most likely that `strtotime` simply didn't understand the supplied parameter format.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. The value being passed in the query string, was not correct. Even though when I printed the value it appeared correctly. Strange problem, but sorted none the less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me using $_GET. Like others, I believe that it is the formatting issue of the string you're getting from the $_GET param.

I tested it with these values: 01/20/2011 - 03/30/2011 and I got the array to print out.

Make sure you clearly analyze what the $_GET param contains and strtotime() will hopefully oblige.

Comment: This is the correct answer because the value being passed in the query string was not the same as what was being displayed, there appeared to be some HTML in the value that was being pass in the TO date, the from date strangely enough was fine. This was  a school boy error and one i'm a little embarrased to admit to! :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
$fromDate = $from;
$toDate = $to;

date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());
$dt = strtotime($fromDate);
$enddt = strtotime($toDate);
$dateMonthYearArr = array();
while ($dt <= $enddt) {
  $dateMonthYearArr[] = date("Y-m-d", $dt);
  $dt = strtotime('next day', $dt);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` is your best friend here.

Im pretty sure there is nothing wrong with PHP. 
Also, `strtotime()` can be picky, watch for formatting and locale (US has month and day swapped around).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I ran

```
<?
$from = "13/01/2011";
$to = "21/01/2011";

$fromDate = $from;
$toDate = $to;

echo $from."\n";
echo $to."\n";


$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);
echo $fromDateTS."\n";
echo $toDateTS."\n";

for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS
+= (60 * 60 * 24)) {
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between
$currentDateStr = date("Y-m-d",$currentDateTS);
$dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
print $currentDateStr."\n";
//print $currentDateStr..<br />.;
}

echo  "<pre>";
print_r($dateMonthYearArr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I got output of

```
13/01/2011
21/01/2011
1325376000
1346454000
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
2012-01-03
2012-01-04
2012-01-05
2012-01-06
2012-01-07
2012-01-08
2012-01-09
2012-01-10
2012-01-11
2012-01-12
2012-01-13
2012-01-14
2012-01-15
2012-01-16
2012-01-17
2012-01-18
2012-01-19
2012-01-20
2012-01-21
2012-01-22
2012-01-23
2012-01-24
2012-01-25
2012-01-26
2012-01-27
2012-01-28
2012-01-29
2012-01-30
2012-01-31
2012-02-01
2012-02-02
2012-02-03
2012-02-04
2012-02-05
2012-02-06
2012-02-07
2012-02-08
2012-02-09
2012-02-10
2012-02-11
2012-02-12
2012-02-13
2012-02-14
2012-02-15
2012-02-16
2012-02-17
2012-02-18
2012-02-19
2012-02-20
2012-02-21
2012-02-22
2012-02-23
2012-02-24
2012-02-25
2012-02-26
2012-02-27
```

So, you know what, it seemed to work for me.

Although it didnt produce the data I expected, but, it certainly didnt exhibit the behavior you saw.

Comment: Of course what it actually decided to do was 1/1/2011 + 13 months to 1/1/2011 + 21 months (not 13th-21st of jan 2011)

Comment: I believe this is because when using strtotime() you need to provide the date in the format YYYY-mm-dd otherwise it doesn't convert correctly.

Comment: Yep, but the code didnt give what I quickly had expected without actually looking at it closely - I just gave it two dates with a difference.  The code did however not do what the OP said and it allowed me to use any of the variables I liked as I had originally expected it would